# Master Override OLAP Cube Connection Settings for all OLAP Grids?

Tags: crystal-reports, olap-cube

I am using Crystal Reports 12.3 and in each of the Reports in my file I have OLAP Grids where I have to set their connection individually. At the moment I am changing it like this for each individual grid:

> Highlight OLAP Grid > (Menu)Database > Set OLAP Cube Location...

Is there a way that I can set a master connection which all of the OLAP Grids reference by default without me having to change it every time?